# Error with Xamarin and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: xamarin

i have a problem with this. Could not install package 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries 4.0.0-beta2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile158', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I am developing in Visual Studio 2015, and when I want to install a PCL project from the Package Manager NuGet I get this error.

Comment: This has to do with NuGet and MVVMCross. I would ask over on this thread: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1088 in their Github Page.

Comment: Yes, we still have not solved it. I can not find solution to the problem